# Why aren't the Asgard in Atlantis?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

Why don't the Asgard go into the Pegasus Galaxy and study Atlantis?

As we see in the *Stargate SG-1* series, the Asgard weren't perfect and couldn't defeat the Replicators but the Ancients had the capability of defeating the Replicators.  The Asgard also knew that the Ancients had more knowledge as well as higher technology.

So why didn't the Asgard go to the Pegasus Galaxy?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know if there's a definitive answer given, but here's some plausible speculation:

- The Asgard may not have known exactly where Atlantis was until the SGC discovered it. Finding it without knowing the gate address would presumably have been very difficult, especially when it was underwater. After its rediscovery, they were close enough to extinction that they could plausibly only afford to send one person (Hermiod) to deal with things (and the SGC may very well have been sharing info with them anyway).
- The Vanir are in the Pegasus galaxy. The Asgard may be trying to stay away from them, either to avoid conflict or because they have some kind of specific territorial no-competition clause.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from @Micah's answer, there are the realities of the Asgard state of affairs. Devastated from the war with the Replicators, with no chance to repopulate due to their cloning problems. They developed a rapid degeneration disease from it. So few survived with no chance of continuing, that there was no reasonable chance that any ancient technology would help in time. If they died without getting rid of their technology, someone like the Goa'uld would come along and use it.

Additionally, the Asgard suffered losses from the Ori, and they probably knew about the Wraith, who were a match for the Ancients at the height of their power. Any Asgard venture into the Pegasus galaxy would mean the Wraith would attack, win, and take over their technology as well. It would not be wise.

Finally, in seasons 9 and 10, Kvasir says Thor and Heimdall are otherwise engaged in another galaxy. They could very well have been in the Pegasus galaxy, we just didn't know.

Answer (score 3):

It was stated in an episode that the Asgard already have the knowledge of the Ancients and that they had barely scratched the surface of it.

> JACKSON: Well can't you just save him, like the last time this
>   happened? Just wipe the Ancient knowledge from his mind.
>
> THOR: And lose any chance of finding a means to defeat the
>   Replicators.
>
> JACKSON: You have no right to risk his life.
>
> TEAL'C: I believe O'Neill would approve.
>
> JACKSON: We can't make that choice for him, no matter what's at stake.
>   Can't you just extract the Ancient information into the ship's
>   computer? Then we can all benefit from it, even learn how to use the
>   Ancient weapons on Earth.
>
> THOR: You cannot even begin to comprehend the extent of what was
>   unfolding in O'Neill's mind. **Our scientists, long ago, extracted parts
>   of the Ancient library of knowledge and learned much from it. But we
>   have been studying it for as long as I can remember, and we have
>   barely scratched the surface.**
>
> JACKSON: So we'd be looking for a needle in a haystack.
>
> THOR: A haystack of infinite size.

[*Stargate SG-1* S8: "New World Order, part 2"](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/New_Order,_Part_2)

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: At worst, they obtained all of it from Jack in _"The Fifth Race"_.